# flowplayer video not playing in google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, flowplayer

notI am using flowplayer js for playing video's in my application with html5,jquery.
It's working fine with firefox,IE and safari ,but the video is not playing in google chrome.
In chrome the video source is there but it remains pause ont playing.
I  will be very  thankfull for your answer.
Sorry for my english.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to add **preload="none"** to your video tags. I've been issued with this problem and finally this helped me. Hope this will help you too.

```
<div id="video">
  <div class="flowplayer is-splash" data-swf="/assets/script/plugins/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.562">
    <video preload="none">
      <source type="video/webm" src="/assets/video/tablet.webm" />
      <source type="video/mp4" src="/assets/video/tablet.mp4" />
      <source type="video/ogv" src="/assets/video/tablet.ogv" />
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```